# How to cancel debounce in ng-model-options in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-model, debouncing, angularjs-forms

```
<form name="editForm">
    Title<input ng-model="task.title" type="text" name=taskTitle ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default' ,debounce{'default':2000000} }">
    <a ng-click="UpdateTask(task.title)">SAVE</a>
    <a ng-click="editForm.$rollbackViewValue();">DISCARD</a>
</form>
```

Since the debounce value is very long, when I click "DISCARD", the ng-model will not reflect its changes.

However, what I want is that when I click "SAVE", either I can change the debounce value or make it expired so the changes will be reflected immediately.

I can't find cancelDebounce() in AngularJs document, anyone would like to provide a solution? Thanks

Comment: make it as variable, instead of 2000000? ... actually, u don't need debounce or ng-model but ng-change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to have one scope variable which will have value of debounce like `$scope.myDebounce = 2000000`, then do create one `discard` function inside controller that will first reset the be-bounce value to `0`, then do rollback the form changes. Reset the `myDebounce` variable to its actual value in next digest cycle.

**Markup**

```
<form name="editForm">
    Title
    <input ng-model="task.title" 
           type="text" 
           name=taskTitle 
           ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default', debounce: {'default': myDebounce } }">
    <a ng-click="UpdateTask(task.title)">SAVE</a>
    <a ng-click="editForm.$rollbackViewValue();">DISCARD</a>
</form>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.myDebounce = 2000000; //somewhere in controller

$scope.discard = function (form) {
   $scope.myDebounce = 0; //resetting debounce to get quick `ng-model` update
   form.$rollbackViewValue(); 
   $timeout(function(){
       //setting the actual debounce value to old one in next digest
       $scope.myDebounce = 2000000; 
   });
}
```

Comment: Brilliant logicI got an error: $timeout is not defined. Do I need to register in the controller?

Comment: @Klyment yes you need to `$timeout` in your controller function

Comment: I am trying to pass the value from scope variable but seems like debounce is not accepting it. I can see the value in consol.log. This is how I am trying;  ng-model-options = "{ debounce: debounceValue  }

Comment: @AbdulWaheed can you provide a plunker of problem statement please?

Comment: Here is the plunker link. I want to stop the ng-change. This worked if I pass value directly. Somehow debounce does not like the value passed from a scope variable. https://plnkr.co/edit/Thb0BCDhdyUw9tU09XFR

Comment: The issue resolved by passing the object instead of concatenating it in ng-model-options value. Now I set the value like  $scope.debounceValue = { "debounce":myscopevariable };  and pass it in ng-model-options="debounceValue ". Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really need is NgModelController.$commitViewValue();

From the [angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$commitViewValue)

> $commitViewValue()
>   Commit a pending update to the $modelValue.
>   Updates may be pending by a debounced event or because the input is waiting for a some future event defined in ng-model-options. this method is rarely needed as NgModelController usually handles calling this in response to input events.